# How to style Android's AppBar action text?

Tags: android, styling, appbar

I need to change text size of action buttons in AppBar/Toolbar. It should be 14sp, but I'll use 20sp in this example, because it is more evident. I am using appcompat-v7 22.1.1

At first I tried to use theme attribute `android:actionButtonStyle`:

```
<style name="FirstAttemptTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Then I ran application on the Lollipop and the result was as needed:

[image]

But then I used an emulator with lower version and my theming had no effect:

[image]

I digged a little deeper and discovered that `abc_action_menu_item_layout.xml` is used for action menu items and it has a line `android:textAppearance="?attr/actionMenuTextAppearance"`
So I tried to modify this theme attribute (I also had to add `textStyle:bold`):

```
<style name="SecondAttemptTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/Custom.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

As in the first time, the result was as needed on Lollipop and no effect on any version below.

**So, the question is: how to properly change text size for action menu item?**

PS: I created a simple project on [github](https://github.com/romanzes/StylingActionMenuTest) to demostrate my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `actionButtonStyle` and `actionMenuTextAppearance` should be used without `android:` namespace.

As it can be seen in values-v21/values.xml of support library, Lollipop uses attribute from system theme (note the `android:` prefix), that's why my attempts worked with it:

```
<style name="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    ...
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">?android:attr/actionButtonStyle</item>
    ...
</style>
```